# Small gearbox PM gears tolerances allowed

Tags: mechanical-engineering

We have a small gearbox design for fire prevention louvres to be opened when a fire is detected by computer software calculation, with PM gears, but the tolerances calculated are very tight. What general tolerance range could we allow for small dimensions ranging from 5mm to 14mm

Answer (score 1):

Usually in the range of 0.01 mm or less for gears that size for actual tooth profile and inspection measurements.